# Swift: "Use of undeclared type" when trying to push to existing view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

so I'm trying to push to existing view controller on the storyboard programmatically ,but I'm getting Use of undeclared type: LoginViewController even that I set the Storyboard ID to LoginViewController here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let ButtonImage = myButton.image(for: .normal),
            let Image = UIImage(named: "ButtonAppuyer.png"),
            UIImagePNGRepresentation(ButtonImage) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(Image) 
        {
            let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("OK")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is LoginViewController? is it defined for your target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you create a new class `LoginViewController` that inherits from UIViewController.

To do so go to the **File** menu > **New** > **File**

[image: new file]

In the **iOS** tab, choose **Cocoa Touch Class**

[image: New Class]

And then **Next**

Give the class name `LoginViewController`, and make it a subclass of `UIViewController`

[image: class name]

Click **Next** and then **Create**. That will add a new file to your project, and you could/should customize its contents later.

In your storyboard, in the **Identity Inspector** tab, make sure to set the class name and the identifier to `LoginViewController`.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Thank you I’m completely new could you please show me example in the code? Thank you!

Comment: I got it. Thank you!